# c++ 2D array fill only top row then bottom row

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

can some one please help me to do this 
 i would like to fill in only the top row first and then the bottom row 
how can i do this this is what i have so far:

```
    const int rows = 2;
    const int columns = 6;
    int grid[rows][columns] = { 0 };  /* 0 0 0 0 0 0 
                                         0 0 0 0 0 0
                                       */


 for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        grid[i][j] = 1; //fill the top row only
           /* Output:
             1 1 1 1 1 1
              0 0 0 0 0 0
            */
    }       
 }

  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            grid[i][j] = 2; //fill the bottom row only
               /* Output:
                1 1 1 1 1 1
                2 2 2 2 2 2
          */
        }       
     }
```

in this case : lets say we dont know the number of rows and columns 
i am a beginner in c++ and arrays please if some one could help

Comment: for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        grid[0][j] = 1;   grid[row-1][j] = 1; 
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for two loops or even a 2D loop. Since you know ahead of time that you're only populating two rows, you can iterate across the columns and specify the rows within the single loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < columns; ++i) {
    grid[0][i] = 1;
    grid[rows - 1][i] = 2;
}
```

Comment: lets say we dont know that there are two rows and 6 columns

Comment: @craftx27 Variables are already in use. This will work for any number of rows and columns because `0` is always the first row and `rows - 1` is always the last row.

Comment: can i do `i++` instead of `++i`

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing in that bit of code is iterating over your array twice. The first time, what is happening, is that **every** item in the array is set to 1. This is because your variable `i` goes from `0` to `rows`, and `j` goes from `0` to `cols`. Thus, when doing `grid[i][j]` this will eventually go through every possibility (`array[0][0]`, `array[0][1]` ... `array[1][0]`, `array[1][1]` ...) if that makes sense.

Then, you are doing the same thing except filling your entire array with `2`s. This is seemingly not what you want. Instead, you should do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
         grid[i][j] = i+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This edits all the rows; OP doesn't want that. He wants first and last rows only.

Comment: Although the fact that the example only has two rows may be confusing...

Comment: Yeah, so in that case, your answer does what he wants :)